# Uber's API returning 404 during CORS preflight request

Tags: javascript, cors, http-status-code-404, uber-api, http-options-method

I'm attempting to use the Uber API in my JavaScript client.

I'm aware that this involves CORS, since my client will be accessing the Uber API directly via AJAX.

In the Uber Developers Dashboard, I set my Origin URI correctly. Then, I set up the most simple example I could find. This came from Uber's docs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Uber API Demo</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'https://api.uber.com/v1.2/products?latitude=37.7759792&longitude=-122.41823');
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Token <ServerToken>");
        xhr.send();
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Looking at the Console in Chrome Dev Tools, this is what I see:

[image: Dev Tools Console]

And, most interesting, the Network tab:

[image: Dev Tools Network]

My browser is changing my HTTP POST into an HTTP OPTIONS request (part of the CORS preflight defined in the fetch spec), which it looks like Uber does not support. Uber's server should reply with the response headers, authorizing my client to finish its API request. Instead, they are returning a 404.

In summary:

- Uber's docs say they support CORS.
- I have my Origin URI set correctly in Uber's Developer Dashboard
- The CORS spec says if I'm doing an HTTP POST with Authorization header, that's a non-simple request and requires the HTTP OPTIONS preflight.
- My browser is doing exactly that, sending a request using HTTP method OPTIONS that includes the Origin header (which matches the Origin URI set in my Uber Developer Dashboard.)
- Uber is returning status 404 (not found)

Anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: When all else fails set up a proxy on a server you control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When making requests to Uber API endpoints from frontend JavaScript code running in a browser, instead of adding an `Authorization` header to the request, you need to add an `access_token` query parameter to the request URL, like this:

```
https://api.uber.com/v1.2/products?access_token=<TOKEN>&latitude=XXX&longitude=XXX
```

See https://developer.uber.com/docs/trip-experiences/guides/authentication#use-bearer-token

> Uber's docs say they support CORS

Yeah, the docs aren’t completely accurate in making that  claim.

> My browser is changing my HTTP POST into an HTTP OPTIONS request…

To be more precise: The browser’s not changing the `POST` into an `OPTIONS`; instead the browser’s doing an `OPTIONS` request *before* trying your `POST` request. And the reason the browser’s doing that is because your code adds an `Authorization` header to the request.

> (part of the CORS preflight defined in the fetch spec), which it looks like Uber does not support

Right. And that’s where the claim in the Uber API docs that they support CORS isn’t completely accurate. They don’t actually fully support CORS; specifically, their API endpoints don’t support handling of CORS preflight `OPTIONS` requests at all.

And adding an `Authorization` header to a request from frontend JavaScript running in a browser causes the browser to do a preflight `OPTIONS` request.

So because the Uber API endpoints don’t support that, you can’t make requests from frontend JavaScript code to Uber API endpoints using an `Authorization` request header to provide the credentials. You need to instead add the `access_token` query parameter to the request URL.